# Is $\sum_{p=n} t^p \otimes 1 = \sum_{q=n} 1 \otimes t^q $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

My vector space is the vector space of polynomials in one variable $k[t]$.  Initially the map $\Delta$ is defined as $$\Delta(t^n) = \sum_{p + q = n} t^p \otimes t^q \text{ and } \varepsilon(t^n) = \delta_{n0}$$ for all $n \geq 0.$ and I was applying $\Delta \circ (\varepsilon \otimes id)$ to the sum $\sum_{p + q = n} t^p \otimes t^q.$ Also, I was applying $\Delta \circ ( id \otimes \varepsilon)$ to the same sum. Finally, I wanted the diagram to commutes i.e., both expressions leads to the same thing. And what I get from both expressions was the two sums given below.

Is $\sum_{p=n} t^p \otimes 1 = \sum_{q=n} 1 \otimes t^q $?

Hope now the question is better explained.

**My guess:**

Yes, and here is the justification:

Both are isomorphic to $t^n.$ But, I do not know exactly what is the isomorphism, could anyone clarify this to me, please?

Comment: Looks like there's a serious lack of context here, not to mention the fact that the sum indeces look really weird (how many $p$'s such that $p=n$? What are we exactly talking about here?). Mind that in general $a\otimes b\neq b\otimes a$ as tensor products.

Comment: Without telling us which kind of spaces you are using to create the tensor product, and what exactly $t$ and $1$ are, this cant't be answered (imho)

Comment: @AndreaMori I will edit my question ...... I am so sorry about that

Comment: @Thomas I will edit my question  ...... I am so sorry about that

Comment: @Emptymind Your explanation "Both are isomorphic to $t^n$" makes no sense. That being said, I posted an answer below.

Comment: Also, the identity you claim that is true, is definitely false, and also makes no sense. $n$ is fixed, so you basically claim $t^n \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes t^n$ which is true if and only if $n=1$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace You mean iff $n=0$ :)

Comment: @runway44 Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you (probably) want to prove is that
$$(\iota \otimes \epsilon)\Delta = \iota = (\epsilon \otimes \iota)\Delta$$
i.e. $\epsilon$ is a counit for the coalgebra structure. Note that this is not what you wrote.

Then
\begin{align*} 
(\iota \otimes \epsilon)\Delta(t^n) &= \sum_{p+q=n} t^p \epsilon(t^{q})= t^n
\end{align*}
since $\epsilon(t^q)\ne 0$ iff $q = 0$, in which case $p= n-q = n$.
It is therefore clear that $(\iota \otimes \epsilon)\Delta = \iota$, since $1, t, t^2, \dots$ forms a basis for $k[t]$. Similarly, we prove that $(\epsilon\otimes \iota)\Delta = \iota$.

Comment: Is $\iota$ the identity map? or something else?

Comment: Your comultiplication is very much *not* the one in the question: you did not rewrite it but changed it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks. Edited.

Comment: @Emptymind $\iota$ is indeed the identity map.

Comment: I think you forgot the tensor product in the definition of $\Delta$

Comment: @Emptymind Sorry where?